# How to know the number of rows loaded by sqlldr?

Tags: scripting, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a table X and I'm loading data from many files to Table X using SQLLDR. I need to know how many rows got loaded into tables

The CTL files contain many conditions, again writing the scripts for filtering and counting will affect the maintainability

Also I dont want to do select count(*) from the table, since it'll be costly operation.

We need to make a seperate repor based on data, like how many rows loaded. And also, we have a timestamo in each row

Answer (score 1):

SQLLDR captures the number of rows it inserted into the table, into the log file.

A sample of the snippet from the log file is:

> SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Feb 7 02:36:18 2013
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Table TBL_TEST:
>
> 0 Rows successfully loaded.
>
> 0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
>
> 0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
>
> 0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.